# Changing default directories for python and ruby

Tags: python, ruby, terminal

Hey :)  I'm working on a Mac with Mountain Lion, and installed both Ruby 1.9.3 and Python 2.7.3 from homebrew.  However, `which python` and `which ruby` return that they are in /usr/local/bin/*_*_, respectively.  I would like them to read from /usr/local/Cellar/python or /usr/local/Cellar/ruby.  How do I change their paths?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you ought to just modify your `$PATH` to include `/usr/local/Cellar` before `/usr/local/bin`. Your shell will use the first one it finds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know on mac but on linux they're set up as links to /usr/local/bin/*

If you wanted to change the symbolic link you could run the command
`ln -s /user/local/Celler/python /usr/local/bin/python` which would make a new symbolic link.

Whether this works on OSX I can't confirm though.

Another method you might want to try is just calling the homebrew versions directly rather than making everything on your system use them. Or just making a symbolic link to something else such as `ln -s /user/local/Celler/python /usr/local/bin/pythonH`